# Не могу сбилдить для ios написанное на nativescript приложение

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript, cocoapods

Добыла макбук для тестирования приложения, написанного на native-script vue. Установила все по инструкции, приложение билдится в эмуляторе Android, но никак не билдится в эмуляторе ios.
Пишет следующее после запуска tns run ios:

```
Preparing project...
Installing pods...
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing MDFInternationalization (2.0.0)
Installing Mapbox-iOS-SDK (4.4.1)
Installing MaterialComponents (84.2.0)
Installing SBToaster (2.1.2)
Installing Socket.IO-Client-Swift (11.1.3)
Installing StarscreamSocketIO (8.0.7)
Installing Toast (3.1.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `spbutestapp.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 5 dependencies from the Podfile and 7 total pods installed.
Project successfully prepared (iOS)
Building project...
Xcode build...
warning: Capabilities for spbutestapp may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the build settings editor. (in target 'spbutestapp')
warning: Stale file '/Users/step-li/workspace/testapp/spbu_testapp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/spbutestapp.app/Frameworks/Starscream.framework' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
warning: Stale file '/Users/step-li/workspace/testapp/spbu_testapp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/10283241104903591256/spbutestapp-Prefix.pch.gch' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
warning: Stale file '/Users/step-li/workspace/testapp/spbu_testapp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/7273211469515386717/spbutestapp-Prefix.pch.gch' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
/Users/step-li/workspace/testapp/spbu_testapp/platforms/ios/Pods/StarscreamSocketIO/Source/WebSocket.swift:668:37: warning: 'characters' is deprecated: Please use String directly
                    if headerSecKey.characters.count > 0 {
                                    ^
/Users/step-li/workspace/testapp/spbu_testapp/platforms/ios/Pods/StarscreamSocketIO/Source/WebSocket.swift:668:37: warning: 'characters' is deprecated: Please use String directly
                    if headerSecKey.characters.count > 0 {
                                    ^
/Users/step-li/workspace/testapp/spbu_testapp/platforms/ios/Pods/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Source/SocketIO/Ack/SocketAckManager.swift:37:9: warning: 'Hashable.hashValue' is deprecated as a protocol requirement; conform type 'SocketAck' to 'Hashable' by implementing 'hash(into:)' instead
    var hashValue: Int {
        ^
/Users/step-li/workspace/testapp/spbu_testapp/platforms/ios/Pods/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Source/SocketIO/Util/SocketClientManager.swift:50:21: warning: static declarations are implicitly 'final'; use 'public' instead of 'open'
    open static let sharedManager = SocketClientManager()
    ~~~~            ^
    public
/Users/step-li/workspace/testapp/spbu_testapp/platforms/ios/Pods/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Source/SocketIO/Engine/SocketEngine.swift:228:23: error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context
        if let data = Data(base64Encoded: noPrefix, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/step-li/workspace/testapp/spbu_testapp/platforms/ios/Pods/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Source/SocketIO/Engine/SocketEngine.swift:520:42: warning: 'characters' is deprecated: Please use String directly
            handleMessage(String(message.characters.dropFirst()))
                                         ^
/Users/step-li/workspace/testapp/spbu_testapp/platforms/ios/Pods/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Source/SocketIO/Engine/SocketEngine.swift:526:49: warning: 'characters' is deprecated: Please use String directly
            handleOpen(openData: String(message.characters.dropFirst()))
                                                ^
/Users/step-li/workspace/testapp/spbu_testapp/platforms/ios/Pods/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Source/SocketIO/Engine/SocketEnginePollable.swift:188:19: warning: 'characters' is deprecated: Please use String directly
        guard str.characters.count != 1 else { return }
                  ^
/Users/step-li/workspace/testapp/spbu_testapp/platforms/ios/Pods/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Source/SocketIO/Ack/SocketAckManager.swift:37:9: warning: 'Hashable.hashValue' is deprecated as a protocol requirement; conform type 'SocketAck' to 'Hashable' by implementing 'hash(into:)' instead
    var hashValue: Int {
        ^
/Users/step-li/workspace/testapp/spbu_testapp/platforms/ios/Pods/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Source/SocketIO/Ack/SocketAckManager.swift:37:9: warning: 'Hashable.hashValue' is deprecated as a protocol requirement; conform type 'SocketAck' to 'Hashable' by implementing 'hash(into:)' instead
    var hashValue: Int {
        ^
/Users/step-li/workspace/testapp/spbu_testapp/platforms/ios/Pods/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Source/SocketIO/Util/SocketClientManager.swift:50:21: warning: static declarations are implicitly 'final'; use 'public' instead of 'open'
    open static let sharedManager = SocketClientManager()
    ~~~~            ^
    public
/Users/step-li/workspace/testapp/spbu_testapp/platforms/ios/Pods/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Source/SocketIO/Engine/SocketEngine.swift:228:23: error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context
        if let data = Data(base64Encoded: noPrefix, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/step-li/workspace/testapp/spbu_testapp/platforms/ios/Pods/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Source/SocketIO/Engine/SocketEngine.swift:520:42: warning: 'characters' is deprecated: Please use String directly
            handleMessage(String(message.characters.dropFirst()))
                                         ^
/Users/step-li/workspace/testapp/spbu_testapp/platforms/ios/Pods/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Source/SocketIO/Engine/SocketEngine.swift:526:49: warning: 'characters' is deprecated: Please use String directly
            handleOpen(openData: String(message.characters.dropFirst()))
                                                ^
/Users/step-li/workspace/testapp/spbu_testapp/platforms/ios/Pods/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Source/SocketIO/Engine/SocketEnginePollable.swift:188:19: warning: 'characters' is deprecated: Please use String directly
        guard str.characters.count != 1 else { return }
                  ^
/Users/step-li/workspace/testapp/spbu_testapp/platforms/ios/Pods/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Source/SocketIO/Ack/SocketAckManager.swift:37:9: warning: 'Hashable.hashValue' is deprecated as a protocol requirement; conform type 'SocketAck' to 'Hashable' by implementing 'hash(into:)' instead
    var hashValue: Int {
        ^
Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build description
** BUILD FAILED **

Unable to apply changes on device: 33923C6D-E086-446F-98C6-2AE5D802A01B. Error is: Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 65.
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": “test-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": “Test Application",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "com.spb.test.app",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "5.4.0"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "5.4.0"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vue/devtools": "5.0.0-beta.3",
    "nativescript-barcodescanner": "^3.1.2",
    "nativescript-bottom-navigation": "^1.5.1",
    "nativescript-cardview": "^3.1.1",
    "nativescript-fonticon": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-mapbox": "^4.4.1",
    "nativescript-platform": "^1.3.1",
    "nativescript-socket.io": "^0.9.0",
    "nativescript-sqlite": "^2.3.3",
    "nativescript-toast": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-toasty": "^1.3.1",
    "nativescript-vue": "^2.2.2",
    "nativescript-vue-devtools": "^1.2.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "^5.4.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5",
    "vuex": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-traverse": "6.26.0",
    "babel-types": "6.26.0",
    "babylon": "6.18.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "next",
    "nativescript-vue-template-compiler": "^2.2.2",
    "nativescript-worker-loader": "~0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.4",
    "vue-loader": "^15.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.31.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "~2.13.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2"
  }
}
```

Подскажите, что я неправильно установила и настроила? Ничего не понимаю в XCode и Swift :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если почитать логи - сразу станет понятно, что используемые библиотеки слегка устарели. Swift очень молодой язык и поэтому от версии к версии немного все ломается.

Вы используете:

> "nativescript-socket.io": "^0.9.0",

А сейчас последняя

[0.10.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-socket.io)

Поэтому нужно пройтись по используемым библиотекам и обновиться до актуальных версий.

Comment: Спасибо) я, правда, уже нашла этот косяк методом тыка :)